# Send mail with zoho smtp server in codeigniter from Google app engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, zoho

I want to send mail by using zoho smtp server from my codeigniter application.

I have tried with below code but I got error.

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.zoho.eu';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'test@example.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '12345678';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('no-reply@example.com', 'Test');
    $this->email->to('test@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject("Test");

    $this->email->message("Test message");

    if(!$this->email->send()){
        $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

I Got below error

[image]

I have hosted the files in google cloud connect. **It's working fine in localhost**

Comment: Hi, which PHP version are you using?

Comment: i'm using 5.6.31

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that in PHP 5.6.0 (at least the version in Debian jessie,
>   with openssl 1.0.1h-3), this function *is* now validating SSL
>   certificates (in a variety of ways). First, it appears to fail for
>   untrusted certificates (i.e. no matching CA trusted locally), and
>   secondly, it appears to fail for mismatched hostnames in the request
>   and certificate.

more on this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)